# WCF Self Host Service Calling with Ajax : 405 Method Not Allowed Error

Tags: ajax, wcf, cross-domain, self-hosting, http-status-code-405

Before posting this question I have gone through lot of similar posts but couldn't find a solution.

I have a Self Host WCF Service in a WinForms application.

**Code:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMathService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "Add/{num1}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(string num1);
}

public class MathService : IMathService
{
    public int Add(string num1)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(num1) + 1;
    }
}
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebServiceHost testHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MathService));
    testHost.Open();

}
```

**App.Config:**

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="S3SelfHost.MathService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8181/MathService" binding="webHttpBinding"

            contract="S3SelfHost.IMathService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have a plain html page and a js file, from which I am trying to call this service which is running on my local machine only.

**JS:**

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8; charset-uf8",
        url: 'http://localhost:8181/MathService/Add/1',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").val(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });

});
```

If I directly hit the hosting url in browser then it shows me the correct result, but when I use same url in js code then it show following error in console.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8181/MathService/Add/1'
>   from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

And in fiddler response header it shows

> 405 Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 0):

For Self-host WCF service created by WebHttpBinding, we could use the following code to enable the support for CORS.
**Reference.**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
```

**Endpoint behavior extension.**

```
public class CustomHeaderMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders;
        public CustomHeaderMessageInspector(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            requiredHeaders = headers ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
            foreach (var item in requiredHeaders)
            {
                httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }

        }
    }
    public class CustomContractBehaviorAttribute : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType => typeof(CustomContractBehaviorAttribute);

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            var requiredHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Pragma, Cache-Control");
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomHeaderMessageInspector(requiredHeaders));
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {

        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new CustomContractBehaviorAttribute();
        }
    }
```

**Apply it in the service endpoint.**

```
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
          <CorsBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="YourNamespace.MathService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8181/MathService" binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="YourNamespace.IMathService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="CorsBehavior" type="YourNamespace.CustomContractBehaviorAttribute, YourNamespace" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client.

```
                //10.157.13.70 is the host that runs the Winform application.
   var serviceuri = "http://10.157.13.70:8181/MathService/add/34";
            $.ajax({
                method:"Get",
                url:serviceuri,
                //contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function(jqxhr,textstatus,err){
                console.log(err);
            })
```

Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is the problem still exists.

Comment: I already tried same with both "POST" and "GET" methods, but still it's not working. I am not sure, but may be <system.webserver> section only works if I host the service on IIS.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't notice your hosting environment, I have changed the reply, please try the code above. feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Besides, please pay attention to the assembly reference.